# How to make a responsive design for Portrait and landscape mode without adding/removing/editing Design and CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm designing a Website for Desktop and iPad. The same website will be used for iPad and Desktop PCs.

Site's design width is 1024px and in iPad Portrait mode it will be 768px. My questions is what things I should consider while making Design and writing CSS so writing specific css for Portrait mode should not be needed

I want to make flexible layout for both orientation without using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use relative width's for everything - think percentages and em's.

Without media queries, it's going to be impossible to serve up different layouts for orientations - however if your design and code is flexible (using relative widths), your design will expand and contract based on the available screen width.

The biggest design concern, in my opinion, would be what the site looks like at 768px wide vs 1024px wide; are the line lengths too long? How will images stretch/contract? Will a font size at 768px be legible at 1024?

Answer (score 0):

The font size will adjust automatically based on the em you set it to, which is a nice thing so you won't have to worry about it.